# Model Conflicts with the Declaration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been getting this error message 'Error 2'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model' and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
 public partial class Person
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", 
         "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Person()
        {
        }
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual EHR_Gender EHR_Gender { get; set; }
        public int GenderID { get; set; }
        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
     }
```

**I created this partial class and add the GenderData property to be able to pass a list of SelectList items.**

```
    public partial class Person
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GenderData { get; set; }
    }
```

**I am getting the conflict error message in the below piece of code.**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender.Description, Model.GenderData, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I have searched on Google for a solution. The majority of the fixes have something to do with someone using 'model' instead of 'Model'. This is not the case for here.

Comment: The code you have shown will not cause that error and its being caused by other code. It is generally a result of using `@Html.SomeMethod(Model => Model.SomeProperty)` (note capital `M` Model) followed by something like `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I was getting so frustrated that I had to leave my desk. Then, I read your comment and come back to check the my code. I went back and meticulously go through the code. Then, I looked at all the hidden fields and found it. Could you put your comment as an Answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown will not result in that error. Its generated because somewhere in you view you have used a `HtmlHelper` method with an expression using capital `M` Model, followed by another reference to `@Model`, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty) 
....
<div>@Model.AnotherProperty</div>
```

Note also that if you swapped the order of the above elements, you would get a different exception.